# Area enclosed between half lines in polar space

Tags: analytic-geometry, area

I don't know if the anwser to my question is obvious because I cannot find any explanation anywhere on google.

Question

The blue region $R$ is bounded by the curve C with equation $r^{2} = a^{2}cos(2\theta)$ $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{4}$, the line $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and the line $l$ which is parallel to the initial line. The point $P(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\pi}{6})$

Show the area of the blue region $R$ is $\frac{a^{2}}{16}(3\sqrt{3} - 4)$.

I tried solving this by finding the area of the rectangle up to $P$ then taking the area of the triangle up to $P$ away as well as the area of C enclosed by the green half line $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ which is where I made a mistake but do not understand why it does not work for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I've graphed the curve and shaded the regions as seen in the picture:

[image: curve]

I know the general method of answering questions like these but what I am really asking is

**Given a polar curve , if I choose two half lines (in this example the green one with equation $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and another half line that does enclose the curve BUT is greater than $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ i.e. it is any half line that encloses the curve but isn't the closest one to it which is the pink one $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ , why do I get a different area than the actual area?**

Is the curve not enclosed by any half line that is greater than $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{6}$ ?

How do I determine the other half line to enclose the curve that is correct then?

In the past I've come across several questions where I could avoid this situation but now since my exams are approaching fast I feel I need to understand this properly.

Answer (score 0):

The portion of R above the $\pi/4$ line (let us call it R1) is half of a square with side $\pi/(2\sqrt(2))$, so that its area is $ \pi^2/16$.

The area of the remaining part of R (let us call it R2) can be calculated as the difference between the area of the triangle delimitated by the lines $\pi/4$, $\pi/6$, and L, and that of the small portion of C above the $\pi/6$ line.

The triangle has base equal to $\pi (\sqrt{3}-1)/(2\sqrt{2})$ and height equal to $\pi/(2\sqrt{2})$, so that its area is  $\pi^2 (\sqrt{3}-1)/16)$.

The area of the small portion of C above the $\pi/6$ line can be calculated by integrating $\frac{1}{2} a^2 cos(2\theta)$ between $\pi/4$ and $\pi/6$ (in polar coordinates, integration of $f(\theta)$ is performed by standard integration of $  (f(\theta))^2/2$). The indefinite integral is $\frac{1}{2}  a^2 sen(\theta)  cos(\theta)$, which calculated over the above mentioned interval yields $\pi^2 (4-2\sqrt{3}/16)$.

Thus the area of R2 is:

$\pi^2 (\sqrt{3}-1)/16 - \pi^2 (4-2\sqrt{3})/16)=\pi^2 (3\sqrt{3} - 5)/16$.

Summing R1 and R2 we get:

$\pi^2/16 + \pi^2 (3\sqrt{3} - 5)/16=\pi^2 (3\sqrt{3} - 4)/16$.

Clearly we could also have obtained the same result more directly as the difference between the  area of the triangle delimitated by the $\pi/6$ line, the y-axis and L, and that of the portion of C above the $\pi/6$ line.

Comment: Why do I get an area different to the actual one if I choose the half line to be greater than $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: When I first worked it out I used pi/2 as the second half line and I believe I did get a different area , I'll try this again now.

Comment: You do not get a different area if you choose a half line greater than  $\pi/4$. In this case, R1 decreases and R2 increases, but their sum does not change.

Comment: I've ended up with $\frac{3\sqrt{3}a^{2}}{16}$ when I used pi/2.

Comment: So I re did the working out and I came up with this $\frac{a^{2}}{16}(3\sqrt{3} - 4Sin(2\theta ))$ derived from $\frac{a^{2}\sqrt{3}}{16} - \frac{a^{2}}{4}  \left[Sin(2\theta)]_\frac{\pi}{6}^\theta $ where $\theta$ is the equation of the half life. If the area as you say will be the same regardless of the value of the half line what is wrong with what I posted here? This provides the correct answer for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ but not for other values.

Comment: Note that, for the calculation of the portion of  C above the $\pi/6$ line, you have to integrate between $pi/4$ and $\pi/6$ even if you choose a second half line greater than $\pi/4$. This is because in the origin the curve has slope $\pi/4$.

Comment: In other words, the second half line is not necessary to calculate the area of the blue region.

Comment: But why does it have to be pi/4 exactly? From pi/6 to a half line greater than pi/4 does that not enclose the curve?

Comment: Yes, but if it is greater than $\pi/4$ it also encloses a new portion of the curve that is negative

Comment: What portion would that be? The curve is only defined for the positive axis

Comment: This is just the point. Since it is defined for theta between 0 and $\pi/4$, you cannot consider higher thetas. For higher thetas, cos (2 theta) becomes negative

Comment: I get that for the curve but how does that relate to the half lines? Does the equation of the half line also have to be within range of the curve's domain? If so that would make more sense to me.

Comment: The equation of the second half line for your specific problem must be $\pi/4$ because it is the slope of the curve in the origin. You can consider other half lines, but these are not involved in no way with your calculations.

Comment: Any half line that satisfies sin(2x) = 1 seems to work e.g. 5/4 pi. Does the equation of the half line also have to be within range of the curve's domain?